# How do I look for bool values in array?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, boolean, filtering, nspredicate

I have an array of objects, each containing a bool value with yes or no. I want to copy all objects with bool YES to another array. How can i do that? i have considered filtering the array using a predicate or integrating it in a for-loop, but i cant seem to get it right.

I need something like this:

```
for (BOOL* opslag_Set in [dataSource allKeys]){
    NSArray *array = [dataSource objectForKey:opslag_Set];
    for (int j = 0; j < [array count]; j++) {
        if ([[array objectAtIndex:j] isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {
            add object to another array;
        }
    }
}
```

First object of my array:

```
    },
    {
    Dato = "2012-11-07 16:20:57 +0000";
    Forfatter = "Vej 51, st. tv.";
    Indhold = "Referat af beboerm\U00f8de";
    "Opslag_set" = 0;
    Overskrift = "Beboerm\U00f8de";
    Prioritet = 0;
    Svar =         (
                    {
            Dato = "2012-11-07 16:23:07 +0000";
            Forfatter = "6. tv.";
            Indhold = "Fedt fedt fedt";
        }
    );
},
```

Comment: Don't misunderstand me, I think it will be better for you if you try to write a code or a pseudo code before. Sorry if you didn't got me right..

Comment: Sorry, my bad:) i will post what i have, but it doesnt work at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use `NSNumber` in order to store the bools in an array.

Assuming your boolean array is called `boolArray`, the code to get an array with only `YES` would be something like this:

```
NSMutableArray* temp = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSNumber* value in boolArray)
{
    if ([value boolValue])
    {
        [temp addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
    }
}
```

However, why are you trying to do this? This will return an array with a certain number of elements that are all the same. You could just count the number if that's what you want. The other thing I can think of is that you have an object with a bool property, in which case you can easily adapt the code above.

**EDIT:** OK, let's assume that we have an object called `MyDataObject` that has a bool property - `NSNumber* boolProperty`. Here is the code:

```
NSMutableArray* temp = [NSMutableArray new];
for (MyDataObject* value in boolArray)
{
    if ([value.boolProperty boolValue])
    {
        [temp addObject:value];
    }
}
```

This should work for what you are doing. `temp` will reference the original objects - they are not being copied.

Comment: Thanks! I get my array from a plist. First i need to count the objects with bool YES and then show them in a collection view with a different header for yes and no

Comment: I guess I'm still confused on what you're trying to do. If you want to display BOTH yes and no, how come you can't just use the array you started with? Are your arrays purely `NSNumber` arrays or do you have custom objects with data that includes a boolean?

Comment: every object contains some strings and a bool. I need an array with only the objects with bool yes. sorry im a little confusing.

Comment: thanks. im not sure about the "MyDataObject part. i added the first object from my array to my original post. What is MyDataObject" in that context?

Comment: You have some sort of data object that holds the bool and string variables. That's what that is.